# Difference between page_view and session_start in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm really confused by the event defined by Google Analytics 4 (GA4). As the title mentioned, does anyone can explain what's the difference between page_view and session_start.

The point is I got much more counts of session_start event (180) than that of page_view (18) for a particular page on the desktop but more page_view than session_start on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Pageviews are the number of times other people view a fixed page, and sessions are how many subpages people viewed. I think so.

Comment: session_start event is fired after if the view is not bounced